# View thumbnails of uploaded images in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I am trying to add thumbnails to list view in django admin.

This is my admin.py for my app, i got this far:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Image
from django import forms
from django.db import models

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("label","tag","order",'Edit','image_img')
    list_editable= ("order",)
    list_filter = ('tag',)
    search_fields = ('tag', 'label')
    ordering = ['-order']
    list_display_links = ('Edit', )
    def Edit(self, obj):
        return "Edit" 
    def image_img(self,obj):
        if obj.pic:
            return '<img src="%s"  height="100px"/>' % obj.pic.url
        else:
            return 'No_image'
    image_img.short_description = 'Image'
    image_img.allow_tags = True    
admin.site.register(Image,ImageAdmin)
```

[image: this is what i get]

My object for picture is called "pic". If I simply add it to list view django returns link with full path. I was looking for template for list view so that I can add |safe filter but I couldn't find it. Any other idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Django > 2.0, you can mark the routine as safe using the `mark_safe()` decorator:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@mark_safe
def image_img(self,obj):
    if obj.pic:
        return '<img src="%s"  height="100px"/>' % obj.pic.url
    else:
        return 'No_image'
```

It can also be used as a function:

```
def image_img(self,obj):
    if obj.pic:
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s"  height="100px"/>' % obj.pic.url)
    else:
        return 'No_image'
```

In older versions of Django, I believe you can just set the `allow_tags` option to true:

```
image_img.allow_tags = True  # Put this after the function definition
```

Comment: Works as magic. Thank you sir. I was looking for way to display images in view and I this code was exactly for older version of Django.